# Use substr in perl to get a part of the string

Tags: regex, perl

I am running a script in different servers and want to pick up the env from the object name. But the object name can differ from server to server.
Object names in different servers:

```
QDEV1,QDEV2,QQA1,QQA2,QCERT1,QCERT2,QPROD1,QPROD2.
```

No I am trying to use substr to get the env as DEV,QA,CERT,PROD. I am taking the object name as an entry to the script.

```
$env = substr($objectname, -4,[3-4]);
print $env;
```

This is returning DEV1/DEV2 when run in dev env and QQA1/QQA2 in QA. I just need the $env to be

```
output(any one of these): DEV or QA or CERT or PROD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just want to use a simple match. For example:

```
$objectname =~ /(DEV|QA|CERT|PROD)/;
print $1;
```

If you just want to get the name without the leading `Q` and trailing numbers you could use:

```
$objectname = "QFOO2";
$objectname =~ /^Q([^\W\d]+)\d+$/;
print $1; # prints "FOO"
```

Or you could replace directly in the variable if you don't want the rest:

```
$objectname = "QFOO43";
$objectname =~ s/^Q([^\W\d]+)\d+$/$1/;
print $objectname; # prints "FOO"
```

Comment: I am getting the objectname from another command where I am splitting the output of a command. I don't think simple match would help. basically, i want to loose the Q in the front and the numbers in the end.

Comment: @user3164754, added an example of how you could do that.

Comment: I have to use it againts the $objectname. i can't use the above code as this part of a script which runs across all envs. Let me explain the whole case
The object name is obtained as `$objectname = (split /\s+/, `pgrep -fl objectprocess` )[-1];` so I need the $env from the above $objectname. I hope this helps you understand my requirement. I can't directly input the value of $objectname.

Comment: @user3164754, obviously the `$objectname = "something";` lines in my examples were just that, examples... Remove that line in the code sample that fits you and use the following two lines...

Comment: If you don't want to change `$objectname` or must have the `$env` variable, then you can use `($env) = ($objectname =~ /^Q([^\W\d]+)\d+$/);`

Comment: I get a syntax error when i run this. ` `(' unexpected error`.